# Decrypt the encrypted file with key in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, encryption, cryptography

I need to retrieve the encrypted datas from QR Scanner by swift. If I scan, some encrypted code I can get it. I dont know how to decrypt the datas. I have searched some examples. In that, private key is mandatory. Now, I am having private key and Encrypted data. If I decrypt that encrypted data, I will get QR Code for which i scanned. If I pass QR CODE and KEY through API, I can retrieve relevant datas. Kindly guide me, how to decrypt that code with key?

Comment: Remember, you need private key for decryption if the encryption is done buy corresponding public key. For symmetric key encryption you need the same secret key for decryption which is used for encryption.

Comment: Moreover, without key you can not decrypt any cipher text(encrypted data).

Comment: Hi @rakeb.void . I got key now. How to proceed in swift??

Comment: I don't know how the confidentiality API works for swift. I just told you the basic. This link can help you though,  [encrypting-and-decrypting-text in swift](http://netsplit.com/swift-generating-keys-and-encrypting-and-decrypting-text)

Comment: I am having only two things,  key and encrypted data? with the above two things how can I decrypt?? @rakeb.void

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79917/discussion-between-rakeb-void-and-mcdonal-11).

Comment: @McDonal_11 First you need to know what encryption method is used, the key length and any options used, add that information to the question. Or provide information or a link to information about the scheme such as QR Droid.

Comment: AES method is used @zaph Can u guide me??

Comment: That is a start, AES is a symmetric encryption method so all previous comments referring to "private key" and "public key" should be ignored. AES encryption has several parameters such as the key size, mode, iv if CBC mode and padding. The plane to start is where the QR code came from and any information supplied about the encryption. Since you have the key and the data from the QR code just try a few combinations and you may find the correct parameters.

Comment: Without more information about the usage an answer would not be helpful to anyone else and thus not a good fit for SO.